# YouTube V3 Data API Quota with User Access Tokens

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

This is more of a clarifying question than anything, but are [YouTube's Data API quotas](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota) applied at the project level, **even when the API requests are made with user access tokens**? Our application authenticates users with Google and passes the access tokens from [that OAuth process](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow) to the YouTube API for each request. However, it looks like the quota is aggregating calls across all users and caping our usage when the *total* usage hits our quota.

We assumed that the YouTube Data API quotas behaved similarly to [Twitch's API rate limits](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/migration#rate-limits):

> ...instead of relying on an app access token that has a set rate limit, consider using a user access token in which case each user of your application is given a rate limit allowing your development to scale as your users increase

Is this not the case for YouTube's Data API? If not, is the only path forward [requesting a higher quota limit](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form)? Is there a service tier that allows us to "pay as we use" the YouTube Data API to mitigate the risk of hitting our quota and affecting our users' access to data from the API?

Comment: Did you work out the answer to this?

Comment: Still waiting on a response, not sure we're gonna get one at this point 

Comment: We asked for a quota increase in the end and they gave it to us. So I don't think there's a usage based API, but they did seem to accept a quota increase that included some immediate future proofing.

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the only path forward

Answer (score 0):

When you send User access token in the request header, do you also send API keys as part of the params?

The documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application) says clearly that only API keys are used to identify projects and then the usage quota. (see [this image](https://share.cleanshot.com/1B4Y1PXq))